# Break list of dictionaries depending upon the keys of dictionary without lossing order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Consider a list

```
temp=[
{'white': ['BlackRock Institutional Trust Company, N.A.  400 Howard Street  San Francisco, CA 94105-2618', ' ', '1,741,814', '', ' ', ' ', ' 6.85%', ' ']},
{'white': ['The Banc Funds Co, LLC  20 North Wacker Drive    Suite 3300  Chicago, IL 60606-3105', ' ', '1,447,529', '', ' ', ' ', ' 5.69%', ' ']}, 
{'blue': ['James B. Miller, Jr.', ' ', '3,413,249', '', '(1)     ', ' ', '13.40%', ' ']}, 
{'blue': ['Major General (Ret) David R. Bockel', ' ', '41,471', '', '(2)    ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['Wm. Millard Choate', ' ', '221,581', '', '(3)   ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['Dr. Donald A. Harp, Jr.', ' ', '40,892', '', '(4)   ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['Kevin S. King', ' ', '53,124', '', '(5)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['William C. Lankford, Jr.', ' ', '32,043', '', '(6)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['H. Palmer Proctor, Jr.', ' ', '309,384', '', '(7)  ', ' ', '1.22%', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['W. Clyde Shepherd III', ' ', '349,450', '', '(8)     ', ' ', '1.37%', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['Rankin M. Smith, Jr.', ' ', '303,768', '', '(9)  ', ' ', '1.19%', ' ']}, 
{'white': ['Stephen H. Brolly', ' ', '48,958', '', ' ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, 
{'blue': ['David Buchanan', ' ', '278,601', '', ' ', ' ', '1.10%', ' ']}, 
{'blue': ['All directors and executive officers  as a group (11 persons)', ' ', '5,092,521', '', '(10)  ', ' ', '19.93%', ' ']}
]
```

I want to break the list into different list whenever the key of dictionary changes. The desired output would be

```
[{'white': ['BlackRock Institutional Trust Company, N.A.  400 Howard Street  San Francisco, CA 94105-2618', ' ', '1,741,814', '', ' ', ' ', ' 6.85%', ' ']}, {'white': ['The Banc Funds Co, LLC  20 North Wacker Drive   Suite 3300  Chicago, IL 60606-3105', ' ', '1,447,529', '', ' ', ' ', ' 5.69%', ' ']}]
[{'blue': ['James B. Miller, Jr.', ' ', '3,413,249', '', '(1)    ', ' ', '13.40%', ' ']}, {'blue': ['Major General (Ret) David R. Bockel', ' ', '41,471', '', '(2)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}]
[{'white': ['Wm. Millard Choate', ' ', '221,581', '', '(3)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, {'white': ['Dr. Donald A. Harp, Jr.', ' ', '40,892', '', '(4)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, {'white': ['Kevin S. King', ' ', '53,124', '', '(5)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, {'white': ['William C. Lankford, Jr.', ' ', '32,043', '', '(6)  ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}, {'white': ['H. Palmer Proctor, Jr.', ' ', '309,384', '', '(7)  ', ' ', '1.22%', ' ']}, {'white': ['W. Clyde Shepherd III', ' ', '349,450', '', '(8)  ', ' ', '1.37%', ' ']}, {'white': ['Rankin M. Smith, Jr.', ' ', '303,768', '', '(9)  ', ' ', '1.19%', ' ']}, {'white': ['Stephen H. Brolly', ' ', '48,958', '', ' ', ' ', ' *', ' ']}]
[{'blue': ['David Buchanan', ' ', '278,601', '', ' ', ' ', '1.10%', ' ']}, {'blue': ['All directors and executive officers  as a group (11 persons)', ' ', '5,092,521', '', '(10)  ', ' ', '19.93%', ' ']}]
```

Key can be more than two (i.e., white and blue)

For now i came up with this logic, but is there any simple or short way to do this.

```
def format(temp):
    i=0
    tmp_list = []
    while i<len(temp):
        found=False
        for color1 in  temp[i]:
            if i+1<len(temp):
                for color2 in temp[i+1]:
                    if color1!=color2:
                        tmp_list.append(temp[i])
                        tmp_list.append("changed")
                        found=True
        if found==False:
            tmp_list.append(temp[i])
        i=i+1
    final_list = []
    another_lis = []
    for tl in tmp_list:
        if tl!='changed':
            another_lis.append(tl)
        else:
            final_list.append(another_lis)
            another_lis = []

    return final_list

whole_list = format(temp)

for wl in whole_list:
    print(wl)
```

Comment: I don't understand *whenever the key of dictionary changes*. Can you explain more clearly how you relate the input to the output?

Comment: If I read his question correctly, he wants to group his data by the first key of each dictionary @BoarGules

Comment: Lets take an example. When you come to 3rd iteration you find out the key as 'blue' -> which does not match the previous key 'white'. so i will break list from that point. 
Note-> any no of keys can be there. 
Thanks, for your time

Comment: If there can be more than a single key, should the solution account for all keys? That is, do you want to introduce a breakpoint whenever any key in a set of keys changes?

Answer (score 5):

An nice way to do this is to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
temp = [...]
data = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(temp, key=dict.keys)]
```

However, as pointed out by Eli Korvigo, this solution is only works with multi-key dictionaries in Python 3.x, since on Python 2.x, `dict.keys()` returns a list object, which is order-sensitive when being compared. As Eli states, an appropriate substitute to use in Python 2.x would be a data structure such as a `set`.

Comment: Thanks, Really great bro.

Comment: I love me some itertools. There is no need to convert `dict_keys` objects into lists, though. They implement `__eq__`, i.e. you can simply pass `key=dict.keys` instead of `key=lambda ...`.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also add that this solution is only adequate for multi-key dictionaries on Python 3.x, because on Python 2.x `dict.keys` returns a list, and list comparison is order-sensitive. Your previous solution had a problem with multi-key dicts even on Py 3.x (due to conversion to list). On Python 2 one can do `key=set`. This will also work on Py3, but in that case the `dict.key` solution is more efficient, because `dict_keys` objects are (computationally cheap) views.

Comment: Hey when i run this it gives me the result but somehow when i implement this in my code i got this error -> "TypeError: keys() takes no arguments (1 given)".

I have checked the input(temp) just before the execution of this line. I am using python 2.7

Comment: @user3809411 can you show your `groupby` call? If you do pass `key=dict.keys` in the `groupby` call and get this error, it is highly likely that you've shadowed the builtin name `dict` with an instance: **don't ever do that** without a very good reason. Moreover, on Py 2.7 you should use `key=set` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I like to have a custom method like the one here below, to be used whenever a **slicing on condition between consecutive elements** is required.

```
def chunk_while(predicate, iterable):
  i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-1:
    if not predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
      yield iterable[x:i+1]
      x = i + 1
    i += 1
  yield iterable[x:size]
```

In this case it can be used in this way:

```
slices = chunk_while(lambda x,y: list(x) == list(y), temp)
```

The result is generator for a a nested array:

```
print(list(slices))

# [
#   [{'white': ['BlackRock Institutional ...', '..']}, {'white': ['The Banc Funds ...', '..']}],
#   [{'blue': ['James B. Miller, Jr.', '..']}, {'blue': ['Major General (Ret) ...']}],
#   [{'white': ['Wm. Millard Choate', '..']}, {'white': ['Dr. Donald A. Harp, Jr.', '..']}, {'white': ['Kevin S. King', '..']}, {'white': ['William C. Lankford, Jr.', '..']}, {'white': ['H. Palmer Proctor, Jr.', '..']}, {'white': ['W. Clyde Shepherd III', '..']}, {'white': ['Rankin M. Smith, Jr.', '..']}, {'white': ['Stephen H. Brolly', '..']}],
#   [{'blue': ['David Buchanan', '..']}, {'blue': ['All directors and executive ...', '..']}]
# ]
```

Comment: `Iterable` objects are not subscriptable, hence your argument names are misleading and even unsafe. Subscription operations (to the extent used in your function) are implemented by classes conforming to the `Sequence` ABC.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I supposed it was ok, since https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile. But maybe I misunderstood something. Can you help me understand why the method doesn't work and why arguments are unsafe?

Comment: As you might've noticed there is no subscription in the snippet you've referenced. All functions in `itertools` are design to work with generic `Iterable` objects. These objects must implement only one method: `__iter__`. You solution relies on subscription and slicing: both are implemented by `__getitem__` of all builtin `Sequence` types, though user-defined `Sequence`s are not forced to implement slicing.